# coc.nvim: how to turn off the errors displayed inline?

Tags: plugin-coc

I've just recently started using CoC.nvim for TypeScript development.

Ideally I'd like the error to only be in the location list, which I have working as shown. The sign column and the location list is sufficient for me; I find the in-line error messages to be very distracting.

I've tried setting `diagnostics.virtualText` but that will display a truncated error message at the end of line 11. It does NOT remove the error text between lines 11 and 12.

How do I get rid of the error message between lines 11 and 12?

[image: vim with coc.vim showing an error message in my code buffer]

Comment: You might use [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) to provide a minimally reproducing example (_e.g._, these plugins, these few lines of config, these few lines of code).

Answer (score 0):

[coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) configuration is specific.

To configure [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) behavior you have to edit a dedicated config file `~/vimfiles/coc-settings.json`.

[coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) provide the `:CocConfig` command to edit the file.

To disable diagnostic you can do:

```
{
    "diagnostic.enable": false,
}
```

To only disable diagnostic message you can do:

```
{
    "diagnostic.enable": true,
    "diagnostic.enableMessage": "never",
}
```

You can also have a folder specific settings `./.vim/coc-settings.json` that you can edit using the `:CocLocalConfig` command.

You can also disable diagnostic temporarily using the following call

```
:call CocAction('diagnosticToggle')
```

Comment: `"diagnostic.enable": false` turns off all diagnostics from coc.nvim, not just the red block in question. `"diagnostic.enableMessage": false,` throws an error of `Value is not accepted. Valid values: "always", "jump", "never". Incorrect type. Expected "string".`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Could you indicate m where/how do you get the error message about the valid values? The solution is working for me? It is working for you too?

Comment: I did `:CocInstall coc-json coc-tsserver` just like [the QuickStart documentation suggests](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/tree/master) and CoC helpfully displayed the error in my CoC config file.

Comment: Thanks I can now reproduce the problem (I though `coc-json` was installed :-|). Is the solution I propose address your problem?

Comment: No.  See my answer.  It wasn't coc.nvim at all.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason I was struggling to find the answer in the `coc.nvim` documentation was that the red block in question wasn't being added by CoC.

It turns out I had `Plug 'mattn/vim-lsp-settings'` in my `.vimrc` file also and that was the plugin that was creating the red text block.

Comment: It would be helpful to future readers to know if there was a specific setting or option in that plugin that created the virtual text issue so they can disable just that setting.